# Collatz Cycles with double the even numbers than odd

Tags: reference-request, collatz-conjecture

This question is with reference to the collatz conjecture. It is known that a number $A$ in a collatz cycle is of the form: 
$$A = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{ 3^{k-i} \cdot 2^{k_i}}{2^n - 3^k},$$
$0 = k_1< k_2 < k_2 ...k_k < n$.

Here, $n$ represents the number of divisions by $2$ in the cycle and $k$ represents the number of odd numbers in the cycle. For the trivial cycle $n = 2k$.

My question is this: has it been shown that there are no non-trivial cycles with $n = 2k$? If so, could i get a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cycle of $a_i$ for $k$ odd steps and $n$ even steps must satisfy a product formula
$$   2^n  = (3+{1\over  a_1})(3+{1\over a_2})\cdots (3+{1\over a_k})
$$
Because the rhs is larger than $3^k$ we must have that $n \ge \lceil k \cdot \ln_2(3) \rceil \approx \lceil 1.5 k \rceil $
If we want $n=2k$ then we have
$$   2^{2k} = (3+{1\over  a_1})(3+{1\over  a_2})\cdots (3+{1\over a_k}) \\
  4^{k} = \underset{ k \text{ - parentheses}}{\underbrace{(3+{1\over  a_1})(3+{1\over  a_2})\cdots (3+{1\over a_k})}} \\$$
and from this, since no parenthese on the rhs can be larger than $4$, no other one can be smaller than $4$ and thus ***all*** of them ***must equal $4$*** and finally all $a_i=1$ is required.

So this all defines the "trivial cycle" $1 \to 1 \to \cdots $ of length $k$ and no other solutions are possible.

---

I have a bit of discussion in my [text on my homepage](http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz061102.pdf) which might interest you although this is no (serious) "reference". *(Unfortunately I do not know any reference which discusses this detail **explicitely** but of course the product formula and some consequences of it are well known at least since R.Crandall<sup>[1](http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz061102.pdf)</sup> in the 70'ies)*

<sup>[1](http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz061102.pdf)</sup> *Crandall, R. E.*, [**On the ”3x+1” problem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2006353), Math. Comput. 32, 1281-1292 (1978). [ZBL0395.10013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0395.10013).